Error on kernel 6.5.0-26-generic, linux-header, anbox-module
Ever since I switched to version 6.5.0-26-generic, I can't boot anymore. I have to switch back to 6.5.0-25-generic every time, and I want to fix the problems there, but as you can see for yourselves, nothing seems to work. Whether it's upgrading Linux headers, updating Anbox modules, deleting, or reinstalling, nothing works. Consequently, I can't install any packages anymore, and unfortunately, I've only had Linux (Kubuntu) on my system for a few months. A friend recommended it to me, and now I'm here, not able to do much, and feeling somewhat at the end of my knowledge.
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-26-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-26-generic all KERNEL_SRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for anbox-binder: 1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64 succeeded for anbox-ashmem
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64 failed for anbox-binder(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-26-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.5.0.26.26); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                 Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (6.5.0-26.26) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-26-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-26-generic all KERNEL_SRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-26-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for anbox-binder: 1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/anbox-binder/1/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64 succeeded for anbox-ashmem
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-26-generic/x86_64 failed for anbox-binder(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-26-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already  
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-26-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

And while booting I get this:


Problem resolved. It was an issue with Anbox, which somehow "crashed" the DKMS folder during uninstallation. After deleting both Anbox folders in the directory /var/lib/dkms, I was able to reinstall DKMS, and it worked without any errors.

Please don't add [FIXED] to the title of original question ... wait until you can accept your own answer, and [SOLVED] will be added automatically when you do so.
